# Prawn gem undefined method `table' for #<FeedbackPdf>

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, prawn, ruby-2.1

I'm trying to get PDF table to work ( following railscast example ) but i get the error `undefined method`table' for #

This is the pdf class lib (followed railscast way of doing) :

```
class FeedbackPdf < Prawn::Document
  def initialize
    super
      text_label
      pdf_feedbacks
  end

  def text_label
    text "Customers Feedback:"
  end

  def pdf_feedbacks
    table[[1,2],[3,4]]
  end
end
```

Can anyone help me please ?

Comment: not sure but in this [doc](http://prawnpdf.org/manual.pdf) I see example `table(data, :header => true)` It means that table is method which accepts some params. According to your code you try to call `table[]` or smth like this (I mean Ruby interprets your code in this way). Try to write `table([[1,2],[3,4]])`

Comment: I did try table([],[]) but i still get the same error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to this [changelog](https://github.com/prawnpdf/prawn/wiki/CHANGELOG), table is now disabled by default in prawn and will be moved in its own gem.

Until then, you can require it at the top of your file:

```
require "prawn/table"
```

Comment: Yes thank you. I solved it by require 'prawn/table' too. Thanks alot. By the way do you know how i can make show different colors for the pie chart in PDF ? I'm currently using prawn-shape to draw the pie charts. But can't color it.

Comment: I never used charts in my prawn documents sorry, but I would recommend the same doc as @gotva, it helped me solve almost all my issues.

Comment: I am using Ruby 2.1.2, Rails 4.1.1. I have same problem as mentioned above, but when i add "require 'prawn/table'" at top of my file it says "cannot load such file -- prawn/table". Any ideas on this?

Comment: hi - any idea in which file and where (location wise) should the entry: 'require "prawn/table"' be added?

Answer (score 0):

As of Prawn 1.2.0, Prawn::Table has been extracted into its own semi-officially supported gem.

Please see https://github.com/prawnpdf/prawn-table for more details.

Gemfile:

```
gem 'prawn-table'
```

Run:

```
bundle install
```

That should fix it.  No need to

```
require "prawn/table"
```

any more.